# Can daily scheduled airflow jobs be paused for specific days, Can cron expressions be used for airflow?

Tags: cron, airflow

I'm relatively new to airflow - scheduling and triggering.
We have few airflow jobs created to run automatically daily, however, we would like to explore options if we could schedule the jobs on daily basis but pause on weekends (Saturday and Sunday).
Is there a way we can schedule the airflow jobs in such a way, or could we use CRON expressions to specify the days, time at which the jobs can be triggered please?

Many thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each DAG may or may not have a schedule, which informs how DAG Runs are created. schedule_interval is defined as a DAG arguments, and receives preferably a cron expression as a str, or a datetime.timedelta object.

For example : Monday - Friday at 00:00

```
schedule_interval = "0 0 * * 1-5"
```